# Derivation of e.q. ( 5.9 ) and ( 5.10 ) in a paper of Kraus et al

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, ads-cft

I want to derivate equation (5.9) and (5.10) in the paper *3D gravity in a box*, https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.13398 by Kraus et al.

First of all, we have a metric in $AdS_3$:
$$ds^2=\frac{d\rho^2}{4\rho^2} +\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{[(1-\rho_c\rho\mathcal{\bar{L}L})d\omega+(\rho-\rho_c) \mathcal{\bar{L}}d\bar{\omega}][(1-\rho_c\rho\mathcal{\bar{L}L})d\bar{\omega}+(\rho-\rho_c)\mathcal{L}d\omega]}{(1-\rho_c^2\mathcal{\bar{L}L})^2}\tag{5.3}$$
We would like to find a vector field that preserving the boundary conditon:
$$\delta_\xi g_{uv} |_{\rho_c}  = (\nabla_u \xi_v + \nabla_v \xi_u)|_{\rho_c} = 0 $$
We start with the ansatz:
$$ \xi^{\omega}(\rho,\omega,\bar{\omega})= f^{\omega}(\omega,\bar{\omega}) + \mathcal{O}(\rho-\rho_c) $$
$$ \xi^{\bar{\omega}}(\rho,\omega,\bar{\omega})= f^{\bar{\omega}}(\omega,\bar{\omega}) + \mathcal{O}(\rho-\rho_c) $$
$$ \xi^{\rho}(\rho,\omega,\bar{\omega})=\rho f^{\rho}(\omega,\bar{\omega}) \tag{5.8}$$
And I would like to see how the boundary conditon can lead to the following equations:
$$ \partial_{\bar{\omega}}f^{\omega} = -\frac{\rho_c \mathcal{\bar{L}}}{1+\rho_c^2\mathcal{\bar{L}L}}(\partial_\omega f^{\omega}+\partial_{\bar{\omega}}f^{\bar{\omega}}) $$
$$ \partial_{\omega}f^{\bar{\omega}} = -\frac{\rho_c \mathcal{L}}{1+\rho_c^2\mathcal{\bar{L}L}}(\partial_\omega f^{\omega}+\partial_{\bar{\omega}}f^{\bar{\omega}}) \tag{5.9}$$
$$ f^\rho =\frac{1-\rho_c^2\mathcal{\bar{L}L}}{1+\rho_c^2\mathcal{\bar{L}L}}(\partial_\omega f^{\omega}+\partial_{\bar{\omega}}f^{\bar{\omega}}) \tag{5.10} $$